# AppSync Lambda Authoriser Source IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I've recently started using a Custom Lambda Authoriser for an AppSync API which has been working great but have found a requirement for the source IP address within that authoriser.

I've been doing a bit of Googling and can find alot of information on how to get the IP address in a velocity template and also how to do this with an API Gateway authoriser but cannot find where to get it in an AppSync authoriser. I'm hoping someone can help.

In the authoriser, if I add this code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
         console.log('EVENT', event);
         console.log('CONTEXT', context);
         console.log('CALLBACK', callback);
}
```

I can see that I do not have access to any headers, I was hoping to see the `X-Forwarded-For` header but it's not there.

```
  EVENT {
    authorizationToken: '<removed>',
    requestContext: {
      apiId: '<removed>',
      accountId: '<removed>',
      requestId: '<removed>',
      queryString: '<removed>',
      variables: {}
    }
  }
```

```
  CONTEXT {
    callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter],
    succeed: [Function (anonymous)],
    fail: [Function (anonymous)],
    done: [Function (anonymous)],
    functionVersion: '$LATEST',
    functionName: '<removed>',
    memoryLimitInMB: '128',
    logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/<removed>',
    logStreamName: '2021/11/25/[$LATEST]<removed>',
    clientContext: undefined,
    identity: undefined,
    invokedFunctionArn: '<removed>,
    awsRequestId: '<removed>',
    getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function: getRemainingTimeInMillis]
  }
```

```
  CALLBACK [Function (anonymous)]
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could expose the IP at the authoriser level?

Here is the auth setup, I can't seem to find any further settings.

[AppSync Auth Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2WIf.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need, but I don't believe the source IP address is available to the AWS Lambda authorizer function, only to resolver functions through the use of $context.identity.sourceIp in the request template.

The only request information available to the authorizer Lambda is

```
{
    "authorizationToken": "ExampleAUTHtoken123123123",
    "requestContext": {
        "apiId": "aaaaaa123123123example123",
        "accountId": "111122223333",
        "requestId": "f4081827-1111-4444-5555-5cf4695f339f",
        "queryString": "mutation CreateEvent {...}\n\nquery MyQuery {...}\n",
        "operationName": "MyQuery",
        "variables": {}
    }
}
```

All the authorizer can really do is validate based on the information received in the request, like an authorizationToken or accountId - and the IP address is not part of the request. I would like to tie a token to an IP address, so that the token is only valid for requests from that IP - however this looks like it needs to be performed on a per-request basis in the individual resolvers after authorization. I can cache the results of the authorizer Lambda using AppSync, but to cache the results of an IP address/token check, I need to do that inside the resolvers. Doable, but annoying to be maintaining authorization code in multiple places.

I'm yet to set how you can modify the request template for the authorizer function - it seems to be a locked down request as above.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the request details inside your event object explicitly using a mapping template (details in AWS doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html#configuring-resolvers). In your case, the mapping template should be similar to this:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "field": "yourField",
        "request": $utils.toJson($context.request)
    }
}
```

When this is done, your Lambda's event object should contain a new property called `request`:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('REQUEST', event.request);
}
```

The console.log should output something similar to this:

```js
{
    headers: {
        'x-forwarded-for': '49.111.222.33, 130.111.222.33',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'cloudfront-viewer-country': 'AU',
        'cloudfront-is-tablet-viewer': 'false',
        'x-amzn-requestid': 'aaaaaaa-ccccc-bbbb-1111-22222222',
        via: '2.0 12345678.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
        'cloudfront-forwarded-proto': 'https',
        origin: 'https://studio.apollographql.com',
        'content-length': '65',
        'x-forwarded-proto': 'https',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,id;q=0.7',
        host: '1234567.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36',
        'cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer': 'false',
        accept: '*/*',
        'cloudfront-is-smarttv-viewer': 'false',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        referer: 'https://studio.apollographql.com/graph/bla/explorer?variant=current',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-321234-123456',
        'x-amz-cf-id': 'A-dadwdewcstd_klA==',
        authorization: 'de2dwqd23...cdwfef43453fewf3few',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
        'cloudfront-is-desktop-viewer': 'true',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"',
        'x-forwarded-port': '443'
    },
    domainName: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, sourceIp is only available if your AppSync authorization method is AWS_IAM or AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS.

You can use x-forwarded-for in $context.request to access the IP addresses from the request header - the leftmost IP address is the source client's IP. I don't think this is available to an authorizer Lambda however, only a resolver Lambda.